# Filtering elements from pandas dataframe for statistical analysis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am fairly new to pandas and I just wanted to check if the following is possible:

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
Date         Hour   id    id_a   id_b   id_c   id_d   id_e
2019-12-05   05     123   True   False  True   False  False
2019-12-05   05     124   False  False  True   False  True
2019-12-05   05     125   True   False  False  False  False
...
```

In excel I can filter values to only show `True` or `False` values and that changes all view and only shows the right columns. I can filter multiple columns and get the desired view. For example `id_a`and `id_b` is set to `True`, `id_e` is set to `False` and other columns are not filtered or accept both `True` or `False` values. For example filtering by `id_a` set to `True` removes the second entry:

```
Date         Hour   id    id_a   id_b   id_c   id_d   id_e
2019-12-05   05     123   True   False  True   False  False
2019-12-05   05     125   True   False  False  False  False
...
```

If is possible to get the following using pandas dataframe with pandas functions or simple python or any libraries:

a ) Return length of dataframe existing if when id_a, id_b are set to false and id_c and id_d accepts any value and id_e is true

b ) Return any combination of `True` and `False` statements.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: `Return any combination of True and False statements` - Can you be more specific? What is expected output?

Comment: The desired functionality is as in excel filters where I can get the item count after applying my filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter only `boolean` columns:

```
df1 = df.select_dtypes(bool)
```

Or columns by positions:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 3:]
print (df1)
    id_a   id_b   id_c   id_d   id_e
0   True  False   True  False  False
1  False  False   True  False   True
2   True  False  False  False  False
```

Then chain masks:

```
m = ~df['id_a'] & ~df['id_b'] & df['id_e']
print (m)
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

And for count `True`s use `sum`:

```
print (m.sum())
1
```

If want count `True`s and `False`s:

```
df2 = df1.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df2)

       id_a  id_b  id_c  id_d  id_e
False     1     3     1     3     2
True      2     0     2     0     1
```

And also filter by some column data before count:

```
mask = df['id_a']
df3 = df1[mask].apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df3)
       id_a  id_b  id_c  id_d  id_e
False     0     2     1     2     2
True      2     0     1     0     0
```

Comment: Thank you, will try it out. If I want to accept either `True` or `False` values I can simply discard any statements filtering that column because it won't make any differences if I accept both values. Using `sum()` to count booleans only counts `True` values? I didn't know that, thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

If df is your dataframe:

a.`df1 = df.loc[df['id_a']==False & df['id_b']==False & df['id_e']==True]
   print(df1.shape[0])`

b. `df2 = df[['id_a','id_b','id_c','id_d','id_e']]
    print(df2)`